# AWS CodeBuild failure on getting source

Tags: aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have CodeBuild project that works fine.
Trying to use it in CodePipeline and it failure with empty Repository and Submitter.
[image: Difference with manual run and from CodePipeline]

Failure logs are simple as:

```
01:34:17
[Container] 2018/03/08 01:34:10 Waiting for agent ping

01:34:17
[Container] 2018/03/08 01:34:12 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
```

There are no any settings to adjust CodeBuild phase anywhere.

How can I fix/customise it?

Comment: Having the same issue here, but now the build ramdomy also fails while running it manually in CodeBuild. Any fixes out there?

Comment: Something similar to this happened to me as I didn't have the code permissions to access CodeBuild in my execution role. Added for anyone else lost and stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Recreate the build project from within CodePipeline, so it receives the source code from the provider called "CodePipeline".

Source of the information: https://apassionatechie.wordpress.com/2018/02/08/codebuild-aws-from-codepipeline-aws/

Comment: You a re right, bu in fact it creates a new one CodeBuild instance. And I know that if I create the whole pipeline from scratch it works. Just curious why it does not work in linkage as far as this option exists.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't a true solution, See my self-answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just if somebody would need an answer.
The issue was in not precise file naming for CodeBuild stage where CodeDeploy in it's turn won't be able to pull the ZIP file.

As a fix I've added an extra command to builspec.yml

```
  post_build:
    commands:
      - zip -r Application.zip target/Application-0.0.1.war
```